# How to group datetime by hour

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to group an array of datetime by hour and return the count of each hour.

This is my list that contains many datetime objects. I try to use a loop to count how many datetime objects are having the same hour but I could not find a way to get the count.

The other references at stackoverflow are all storing date as a column in pandas which I do not want, because my datetime are store in a list.

I am hoping to get a list of hour_count objects that looks like this

```
hour_cound = [
    { 
        "hour": datetime,
        "count": 2
    }
]



# code

hours = [
    datetime(2019, 1, 25, 1),
    datetime(2019, 1, 25, 1),
    datetime(2019, 1, 25, 2),
    datetime(2019, 1, 25, 3),
    datetime(2019, 1, 25, 4),
    datetime(2019, 1, 25, 4)
]

existed = []
for hour in hours:
    if hour.hour not in existed:
        existed.append({
            "hour": hour.hour,
            "count": existed[hour.hour] + 1
        })
```

Comment: Just do `set([hour.hour for hour in hours])` to get a unique list (set) of hours from the dates.

Comment: Your desired output is unclear but I think you can get pretty close if you use `collections.Counter` and do `Counter(h.hour for h in hours)`. Or maybe you're looking for `hour_count = [{"hour": h, "count": c} for h, c in Counter(h.hour for h in hours).items()]`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1Your suggestion gets me unique list of hour but it couldnt get counts...

Comment: @pault Your solution looks right, yes I only need to get a list of objects with hour and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper method from pandas to store your list of hours and then use numpy to generate unique counts for each unique hour.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

hours = pd.DatetimeIndex(hours).hour
unique_hours, counts = np.unique(hours, return_counts=True)
hour_count = [{ "hour": hour, "count": count } for hour, count in zip(unique_hours, counts)]

pprint(hour_count)
```

---

Result

```
[{'count': 2, 'hour': 1},
 {'count': 1, 'hour': 2},
 {'count': 1, 'hour': 3},
 {'count': 2, 'hour': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing without using `pandas` is to use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(h.hour for h in hours)
print(counts)
#Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2})
```

Now just reformat into your desired output using a list comprehension:

```
hour_count = [{"hour": h, "count": c} for h, c in counts.items()]
print(hour_count)
#[{'count': 2, 'hour': 1},
# {'count': 1, 'hour': 2},
# {'count': 1, 'hour': 3},
# {'count': 2, 'hour': 4}]
```